# Finding multiple Elasticsearch documents with same ids, different types

Tags: elasticsearch, duplicates

I need to find out if any document with a certain id was already indexed in my ES database, so that I can delete them before indexing a new document.

The trouble is I do not know a priori the *type* it was indexed as.
I found the _mget query which sounds like it could be what I need, but then this quote in the documentation says I only get 1 (random) hit when searching

> If you don’t set the type and have many documents sharing the same
>   _id, you will end up getting only the first matching document.

how can I get this behaviour; finding all documents sharing an _id, possibly > 1 with different _type in the same index without an expensive _search query?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) on `"_id"` worked for me.

So I created a trivial index and added two documents each, for two different types:

```
PUT /test_index

POST /test_index/_bulk
{"index":{"_type":"type1","_id":1}}
{"name":"type1 doc1"}
{"index":{"_type":"type1","_id":2}}
{"name":"type1 doc2"}
{"index":{"_type":"type2","_id":1}}
{"name":"type2 doc1"}
{"index":{"_type":"type2","_id":2}}
{"name":"type2 doc2"}
```

And this query will return both documents with id 1:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "constant_score": {
         "filter": {
            "term": {
               "_id": "1"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 5,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "type1",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "name": "type1 doc1"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "type2",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "name": "type2 doc1"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here's the code I used:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/a8085b57c22631148dd4c67769307caf6425fd95